# Error ClassFormatError en la ejecución de una applet

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, activex

Solamente sé Java o Javascript a nivel de usuario. Ni tan siquiera programo en esos lenguajes.

Tengo una applet que antes, en windows XP y windows 95 funcionaba y ahora no. La uso para hacer demostraciones docentes.

Tengo instalado Java SDK versión 8u-181 (x86) y la ejecuto mediante el navegador iExplorer de Microsoft. El código dentro del archivo "kk.htm" hace una llamada a la applet en cuestión mediante un Script de JavaScript.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="Mozilla/4.03 [de] (Win95; I) [Netscape]">
<TITLE>Muestreo</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript SRC="jscript/config.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<A NAME="applet"></A>
<CENTER><B><I><FONT COLOR="#000000"><FONT SIZE=+2>Applet del muestreo </FONT></I></B></CENTER>
<BR><BR><BR>
<CENTER>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>checkApplet('sampling')</SCRIPT>
</CENTER>
<BR><BR><BR>
<HR>
<BR><BR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Cuando ejecuto el "kk.htm" mediante el iExplore, se abre una pestaña en el explorador que me pide habilitar contenido bloqueado. Una vez desbloqueada la ejecución de ActiveX y Scripts, obtengo el siguiente RunTime Error:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid start_pc 531 in LocalVariableTable inn class file wiener/Main

Parece ser un error en la programación del applet de Java. Lamentablemente, yo no dispongo del código fuente de la applet; sólo del ejecutable.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? ¿Se podría decompilar la Applet y separarla en clases?

Comment: Si el código específico del archivo es ese, es que está incompleto.

Comment: Ahora está mejor editado. Antes no se veía parte del código

Comment: Recuerda que los applets están "obsoletos" para poder usarlos debes usar una versión de java inferior a la 7, y hasta un favor a ti y principalmente a tus estudiantes, no les enseñes algo que no usaran..

Comment: Uf, vaya respuesta de poca ayuda. Yo no estoy enseñando a programar (de hecho, si estoy aquí es porque no soy programador). Enseño otras cosas. Dicho lo cual, estoy utilizando otros applets con Java 8 (x86) + iExplore y funcionan a la perfección. Son utilísimos en demostraciones sobre PowerPoint. Preferiría que me dieses alguna solución a mi problema y no una vaguedad imprecisa. Gracias.

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con JavaScript, el error es de Java. Necesitariamos ver el codigo del applet para ver que ocurre.

Comment: @JDev : Pues no tengo el código del applet. Es un .jar que me mandó un colega hace años y ahora es imposible obtener las fuentes. Lo que sí sé es que ha funcionado hasta que empezaron las restricciones de seguridad en Java. Es el único que no me funciona. Los demás que tengo los he hecho funcionar con el iExplore, como he dicho más arriba.

Comment: Me da la impresión de que el lenguaje Java con el que se escribió el .jar no era del todo estándar, al menos para Sun/Oracle que es quien ha seguido actualoizando Java. Por tanto, lo que ocurre es que da un error de ejecución debido a una mala sintaxis que ahora, con las versiones actuales de Java, no corre y hace años sí se ejecutaba.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he PSEUDO-RESUELTO, es decir, que no he solucionado el problema, pero lo he circunvalado, haciendo que la applet se pueda volver a utilizar Entonces:
a) He instalado un terminal virtual VMware (Workstation Pro v15). 
b) Dentro de ella he instalado Windows XP + SP3 + MSJVM_v3805 con su actualización MSJavWU_807368. (No he instalado ninguna versión de Oracle Java) + Internet Explorer v7. (¡con MSIE_v8 no funciona!).
c) Ejecuto la applet abriendo un .html conteniendo el código indicado en la pregunta.

SIGO EN BUSCA DE AYUDA para encontrar una SOLUCIÓN DEFINITIVA al problema (tal vez decompilando la applet).